# Why incorrect convert from string to date?

Tags: datetime, kotlin

In my Kotlin code:

```
   const val TS_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
   val ts = responseJsonObject.get("TS").getAsString()
   val tsDate = SimpleDateFormat(TS_DATE_PATTERN).parse(ts)
   val tsDateAsString = SimpleDateFormat(TS_DATE_PATTERN).format(tsDate)
   logger.info("ts = " + ts + " -> tsDate = " + tsDate + " -> tsDateAsString = " + tsDateAsString)
```

And here the (formatted for readability) result:

```
ts             = 2019-01-14T22:56:30.429582 
tsDate         = Mon Jan 14 23:03:39 EET 2019 
tsDateAsString = 2019-01-14T23:03:39.582
```

As you can see the **ts** and **tsDateAsString** have different times, although they came from the same starting point.

E.g. `ts = 22:56:30` but in `tsDateAsString = 23:03:39`

Why?

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion: whenever you can, use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html)-utilities.

[`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) has a special handling for the milliseconds. Everything that is parsed by the `S` is treated as milliseconds. As long as you deal with 3-digit-milliseconds, everything is fine (you may even just use a single `S` (i.e. `.S`) for the milliseconds to parse them), but if you use 6-digit-milliseconds as input then you also get a 6-digit-millisecond(!)-value.

The 6-digit-milliseconds then are actually 3-digit seconds + the 3-digit milliseconds. That is where the deviation is coming from.

How to solve that? Well either shorten the input time string and lose some precision or use the preferred [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead with a pattern matching your input, i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`:

```
val TS_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(TS_DATE_PATTERN)

val tsDate = formatter.parse(ts) // now the value as you would expect it...
```

Transforming that to a `TimeStamp` will work as follows:

```
Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.from(tsDate))
```

Comment: @Alexei adapted the answer to your actual problem.

Comment: Also I need to convert tsDate (TemporalAccessor)  to TimeStamp. How I can do this?

Comment: `Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.from(tsDate /* the parsed one */))`

Comment: @Alexei If you thought you needed to convert to `Timestamp` for your SQL database, you were probably wrong. JDBC handles `LocalDateTime` and other java.time types since version 4.2. A modern JPA implementation does too.