# LocalDateTime in format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS?

Tags: kotlin, timestamp

In my Kotlin code I generate current date like this:

```
val dtTimeStamp = LocalDateTime.now()
logger.info("dtTimeStamp = " + dtTimeStamp)
```

The result is:

```
dtTimeStamp = 2019-01-15T10:43:06.777
```

But I need LocalDateTime in format **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS**

So the result must like this (e.g.):

```
2019-01-15T10:43:06.170268
```

How I can do this?

Comment: don't mistake formatting i.e. string representation with object representation... the format only has value if you parse a value from a string or if you decide to output it, e.g. to a log.... a `Timestamp` or a `LocalDateTime` has all the precision you require... it has years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, nanoseconds... (or at least you can get it from those objects)

Comment: I need LocalDateTime in format  yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS to insert in database.

Comment: ... you don't have to think about the format in the target database, except that column type would be a `VARCHAR` or similar... you setup a `Timestamp` and ~give it to your database handling object... (depending what you use: JDBC or JPA)...

Comment: what do you use to add data to your database?

Answer (score 3):

You can format it with the same formatter you used to parse it (e.g. the one you used in [Why incorrect convert from string to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54183696/6202869) ).

Again I recommend using [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) (you are even using `LocalDateTime`, so that will be fine ;-)):

```
val TS_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(TS_DATE_PATTERN)

// formatting:
tsDate.format(formatter)
// or:
formatter.format(tsDate)
// or if you rather prefer it:
tsDate.let(formatter::format)
```

All 3 variants return a formatted `String` in the form: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS` (e.g. `2019-01-14T22:44:20.765123`), where `tsDate` would be got via:

```
// parsing:
val tsDate = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse("2019-01-14T22:44:20.765123"))
```

Note that if you use an object in while printing/logging or just referencing it in a `String` it will use [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) to get a `String` representation, in this case from [`LocalDateTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString()). That's probably fine most of the time for debugging/logging purposes, but might not be ok for anything else. So you shouldn't rely on `toString()`.

Comment: I already answered that in the other question... it's still `Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now())`... you may also want to consider Ole V. V.s comment regarding the automatic conversion...